# Can i get a reference to an object constructed inside a function?

Tags: java, spring, reflection

I have the following problem: I need to send some query parameters to send to a database from inside a java function inside a rest controller. However depending on the method exposed as an API, I need to update my query object dynamically.
The function API looks like the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getItems, method = { RequestMethod.POST }, produces = { "application/json" })
public List<Item> getItems(){
  QueryObject queryObject = new QueryObject();
  queryObject.setParam(param);
  List<Item> items = dao.getItems(queryObject);
}
```

What I would like to do is make some sort of a mechanism, that by simply annotating the exposed API methods for which I want the enrichment of the query object, to add query params to the query object. Reflection can't achieve that, neither AOP feature of Spring. I wasn't able to find a mechanism that gives me a reference to an object instantiated inside a method.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that. Even if you could do that somehow (through reflection for example), it would be really bad design. Write the method so it can take additional parameters instead.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getItems
public List<Item> getItems(){
```

neeeds to be changed to

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getItems/{param}
public List<Item> getItems(@PathParam("param")Param param) {
```

Comment: not quite what i need, but thanks anyhow, what i need can't be done

Comment: Just being curious because this seems to be https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem what is the actual problem ?

Comment: no XY problem here, it is just that what i need can't be done(although i tried) through the instruments that Java makes available to developers.This is why i detailed what i already tried so that people do not try what i tried and doing so losing time. I was just wondering if someone else has other ideas than mine. It seems not because what i asked can't be done in Java. If you think that you should waste your time with XY problems you can signal this to the admins, although the question is perfectly valid and involved research. It is just that Java does not allow what i need.

Comment: the question is the one in the title: **Can i get a reference to an object constructed inside a function?** The description represents what i tried so far so that people do not waste time with what i already did.

Comment: Sorry i stated i'm curious why you need this not complaining wasting my time

Comment: i need this in order to make the code more configurable, in my view code should be written in such a way that it configurable, at least this is one key point that i.e. Spring, Hibernate has.

Comment: not an answer to your original question but just a thought: afaik in AOP it is not possible reference local variables inside method but if you made this `param` as a member of this REST service and manipulate it synchronized in aspect that checks annotation before the method  that just might work. but still might be quite messy solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156371/discussion-between-carolik-and-pirho).